# Edit Mapping Hive/Hbase

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I'm using Hbase with hive. So I created a table in hbase :

```
Create 'tableHbase' 'd'
```

and create my hive table like this :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hbaseTable_hive(key String, c1 string, c2 string) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,d:c1,d:c2")TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "hbaseTable");
```

But now i want to now if it is possible to :

1- when i add a new column in hbase (d:c3) the value of c3 can't be showen in Hive. Is there a possibility to see it in hive without editing or recreating the hive table.

2- Edit this mapping (to add a new column for example (c3 string)). without deleting the hive table and recreate it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither 1 or 2 are possible.

- #1:  Hive requires explicit mapping from the hbase columns so .. no .. hive will not see it without updates to the mapping.
- #2 The hive "alter table" syntax does not support #2. You will need to drop and recreate the hive table with the updated mappings.

Answer (score 0):

You can not alter `SERDER` properties for an external table.
What you could do is to remove link between your table and the external source.
Example if is an Hbase table, you can do:

1. ```
   ALTER TABLE MY_HIVE_TABLE SET TBLPROPERTIES('hbase.table.name'='MY_HBASE_NOT_EXISTING_TABLE')`
   ```

   NB: `MY_HBASE_NOT_EXISTING_TABLE` must be a non existing table.
2. `DROP TABLE MY_HIVE_TABLE;`
3. Recreate your hive table by specifing your new SERDE Properties

   ```
   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE MY_HIVE_TABLE(
   MY_colums
   )
   ROW FORMAT SERDE 
     '...' 
   WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (...)
   TBLPROPERTIES (
       'hbase.table.name'='z_app_qos_hbase_temp:MY_HBASE_GOOD_TABLE'
   );
   ```